SharePoint Online Make only 3 columns appear per row using configure layout
SharePoint online, is it possible to make only 3 columns appear per row using configure layout?
I'm using SharePoint online modern experience and want to display only 3 columns per row only using configure layout or out of the box solutions.
I don't have the option of using Power Apps or other 3rd party applications.
please check the code snippet below I am using:
{
        "displayname": "Personal Info",
        "fields": [
            "ID Type",
            "Origin of ID Type",
            "ID/Passport Number",
            "Personal Title",
            "Initials",
            "First Names",
            "Surname",
        ]
    },
    {
        "displayname": "Occupation Details",
        "fields": [
            "Employee No",
            "Employee Type",
            "Area of Employment",
            "Country Of Employment",
            "Working Hours"
        ]
    }

So for example on the first row I want to display only "ID Type", "Origin of ID Type", "ID/Passport Number" and so fourth. currently by default it displays 4 columns per row.

Can you try using this Configure Body sections on list form? Let me know if it works for you or if there are any challenges.

@GaneshSanap-MVP I appreciate your assistance but the link you shared don't necessarily address my problem.

In the body configure layout of new form, it only allows defining one or more sections and adding one or more columns into each of those sections. Until now, you cannot specify how many columns per row.
{
    "sections": [
        {
            "displayname": "Personal Info",
            "fields": [
                "ID Type",
                "Origin of ID Type",
                "ID/Passport Number",
                "Personal Title",
                "Initials",
                "First Names",
                "Surname"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "Occupation Details",
            "fields": [
                "Employee No",
                "Employee Type",
                "Area of Employment",
                "Country Of Employment",
                "Working Hours"
            ]
        }
    ]
}



Hi okay thank you for the clarity. I also decided to abandon this nice to have as I realized its quite impossible without power apps or spfx.

Yes, Power Apps is a better method.
